# Merging two rows in pandas into one

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this

```
no, frc, val 
1121,1,"John"
1121,0,236
3612,1,"Mary"
3612,0,545
```

I want to combine data like this

```
"John",236
"Mary",545
```

Comment: If it's just a pandas question, please avoid adding tags that are not relevant to your problem. I don't need to know neural networks to solve your problem, for example, so there's no need to tag it machine learning.

Answer (score 2):

you can self join two subsets of this DF, using `merge()` method:

```
In [21]: (df[df['frc']==1]
            .drop('frc',1)
            .rename(columns={'val':'name'})
          .merge(df[df['frc']==0].drop('frc',1)))
Out[21]:
     no  name  val
0  1121  John  236
1  3612  Mary  545
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df.set_index(['no', 'frc']).val.unstack().rename(columns={0:'val', 1:'name'})

frc   val  name
no             
1121  236  John
3612  545  Mary
```

---

Or to produce OP output

```
print(
    df.set_index(['no', 'frc']).val
      .unstack()[[1, 0]]
      .to_csv(index=False, header=False)
)

John,236
Mary,545
```

Comment: yeah, this solution is much more conscious!